# Kubernetes guestbook-controller failing with permission denied error

Tags: php, kubernetes

I am following the guestbook example for kubernetes on gce:

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook

I am able to complete up to step 4, exactly as it is described in the tutorial (all outputs match), however when I try to initialize the guestbook web server pods with

`create -f $CONFIG_DIR/guestbook-controller.json`

I get the following output with when using  `kubectl get pods`

`guestbook-controller-2mjqj Pending About a minute php-redis
API error (500): Cannot start container containerID: [8] System error: open /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/containerID/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes: permission denied`

I haven't been able to find anything related to this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed last week in Kube:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/8814